# saudi labour can visit kuwait

Tags: indian-citizens, tourist-visas, kuwait, gcc

I am indian with saudi visa holder of proffision مشرف العمل labour supervisor can i visit on araival to kuwait with my family they are holding 2yr family visit visa 
please suggest an easy way.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if your profession qualifies to obtain an e-visa for Kuwait. Their list of acceptable professions for GCC residence permit holders is very short. But you can try to [apply for the e-visa](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/) at their official web site.

You can apply for an e-visa if you are one of a few listed nationalities, or any nationality can apply who has a GCC residence permit with at least six months validity and one of the list of professions on the official e-visa web site:

> Consultants
>   Doctors
>   Engineers
>   Lawyers
>   Judges&Members of Public Prosecution
>   University Teachers
>   Press&Media Staff
>   Pilots
>   System Analysts & Computer Programmers
>   Managers
>   Businessmen
>   Diplomatic Corps
>   University Graduates – Owners, Managers and Representatives of Commercial Companies and Establishments

Kuwait's list of acceptable professions seems quite short; each GCC country decides which professions it will accept for entry with an e-visa or visa on arrival and they are usually much longer lists.

You can always try to get the e-visa. If it is refused then you will need to get a regular visa from the consulate.